# Can't su to login on other user

Tags: ssh, debian, su

I have a Debian server, and I can SSH to it.. On SSH there I'm prompted to specify username and pass, I can login here as any user I want..

If I'm root I can change to other users, for example with: "su luxo" to login on user luxo.

But if I'm logged in as another user, I can't login to root, or even other users.. It allways gives an "authentication failure" notify.

How can I solve this? If I want to change user now I have to open a new SSH session every time..

Comment: If you log in as `user` are you able to execute `su` (with no other parameters, typing in the password for the root user, and becoming the root user)?

Comment: Please paste the output of `ls -ld \`which su\`` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't switch from one user to another via `su user` - it has to be done as root user. Only way I know to do this as user is via `sudo` command, so it looks like

```
sudo su user
```

If you're able to access root account by doing `su` or `su -` (which automatically cd's to root $HOME) everything is ok.

Comment: You can use `su` as a normal user, but you'll be prompted for the new user's password.